# Finding the next larger anagram of a given number

Tags: data-structures, anagram

What would be an efficient algorithm to find the next larger anagram of a given number?

Examples:

1. input: 7813  ->  output: 7831
2. input: 3791  ->  output: 3917
3. input: 4321  ->  output: (None)

Comment: wouldn't your example 2 look more like 3791 => 3917

Answer (score 3):

Basically you move through the number from right to left.  Once you find a decreasing digit, then you stop.  Compare that digit with all of the previous digits.  Replace it with the next highest digit, then sort the rest in increasing order.  For example:

take 978654321.
1) move right to left until you get to a decreasing digit:

```
Stop at the 7 because that is the first digit that decreases.
```

2) find the next largest digit that we have already seen:

```
out of 1 2 3 4 5 6 and 8, 8 is the next largest digit to 7.
```

3) sort the remaining digits in increasing order and append that to the end.

```
1234567
```

Which produces 981234567

complexity:

n is the number of digits.

Step 1) O(n) because in the worst case the numbers increase (or stay the same) until the last digit.

Step 2) O(n) because in the worst case you have to compare that number against all of the n digits.

Step 3) O(n lg n) because you have to sort and the best sorting algorithm is nlgn.

So this algorithm runs in O(n lg n). again where n is the number of digits in the number.